# Cannot share video with UIActivityViewController in IOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

I get error when share video with UIActivityViewController in IOS > 14, but iOS under 14 worked fine. I don't know why?

2021-03-15 23:55:20.866820+0700 AnyBackup[3249:1433997] Could not create sandbox extension. Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not create sandbox extension of type com.apple.app-sandbox.read for URL /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0415.MOV. Error: Operation not permitted}

2021-03-15 23:55:20.867564+0700 AnyBackup[3249:1457502] [default] Failed to ssue sandbox token for URL: 'file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0415.MOV' with error: 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot issue a sandbox extension for file "/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0415.MOV": Operation not permitted}'

I need a help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure your video available in your `DocumentDirectory` and than you can share it via `URL of Directory` like below.

**Share Video with URL:**

```
let url = self.documentDirectory().appendingPathComponent("yourFilename")
let share = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
share.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(share, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Get URL of DocumentDirectory:**

```
func documentDirectory() -> URL {
  let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
  return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your suggested.

Comment: you're welcome. If my answer is useful you can upvote it.